# Error variance estimation in least-squares regression

Tags: regression, variance, cross-validation, least-squares, residuals

Consider a regression model:

\begin{align*}
y = f({\bf x}; {\bf b}) + e\tag{1}
\end{align*}

where $y$ is the objective variable, $\bf x$ is the explanatory variable(s), $\bf{b}$ is the model coefficient(s), and $e$ is the error term.

In the "simplest" least-squares fitting of the model to the observation data $({\bf x}_i, y_i)$ $(i = 1, 2,\ldots, n)$, ${\bf b}$ is optimized to minimize the Sum of Squared Residuals (SSR), where $i$-th residual is defined as $y_i - f({\bf x}_i; \hat{\bf b})$ and it uses the estimator $\hat{\bf b}$ of ${\bf b}$.

The population variance of e is often estimated by "reduced chi-squared statistic":

\begin{align*}
\text{SSR} / (n - nb)         \tag{2}
\end{align*}
where $nb$ is the number of the coefficients (the number of the elements in {\bf b}).
The sqrt of (2) is often called "residual standard error."

I'd like to ask whether (2) is a "good" estimator of the error variance even when $e_i$ is not independent of each other.

For example, when $e_i$ and $e_j$ are correlated for some pairs of $i$ and $j$ $(i, j = 1, 2,\ldots, n)$, does (2) still have some good properties like unbiasedness and/or consistency?

If not, how about the sample variance of prediction errors by LOO cross-validation? Will it give a "good" estimate of the population variance of $e$ even when $e_i$ is not independent of each other?

I am confused about this for a few days...